# Extract json data from given string

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string something like this :

```
a.b.c.d.e = 
{"altImages":2,"available":1,"availableColorCount":3};
```

Now I only need to fetch :

```
{"altImages":2,"available":1,"availableColorCount":3}
```

What should be regex expression to extract that part from given string. Please help

My Try :

```
(?smi)a.b.c.d\\(.*\"e\"=(.*?)\\}\\);.*
```

But its not helping around.

Comment: And you can't just split on the "="?

Comment: Or search for the first index of '{' and the last index of '}' and get the substring ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.+\s*=\s*({(?:.+:.+,?)+})(?=;)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this ? And is this complete answer ? Or I mean there is something at start too : (?smi)a.b.c.d\\

Comment: Updated my answer to include the first part of the string, even though I personally don't deem that necessary unless you're using differently formatted jsons and only want to grab the ones formatted as mentioned above.

Comment: I need to pass it as string to function. but getting errors. ".+\s*=\s*({(?:.+:.+,?)+})(?=;)" not working

Comment: Can you post what you're trying exactly? The regex above definitely catches what you specified in your question. https://regex101.com/r/zN4pA6/1

Comment: I mean can you escape special characters so that I can assign it to java string ?

Comment: But I need to fix the part a.b.c.d.e.

Comment: In that part, you likely need to escape the \s as follows: \\s

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
.*?\n(.*);
```

Here is the version with named groups:

```
String text = "a.b.c.d.e = \n{\"altImages\":2,\"available\":1,\"availableColorCount\":3};";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\n(?<JSON>.*);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group("JSON"));
}
```

Comment: Your regex would also catch something like int a =
2;

Comment: If that's a restriction, we just need to add `\\{` and `\\}` before and after the named group. Let @GitCoder decide if your example should be matched or not.